# Accessing process.env.PORT defined in Elastic Beanstalk Node, bundle built by Webpack

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Currently I'm building out a REACT app on my local machine and deploying it's production build to Elastic Beanstalk. It is built using Webpack.

In index.js (server side) I use env variables such as: process.env.PORT (Defined in Elastic Beanstalk), when Webpack builds it out, these are replaced with Objects({}) containing local process.env.

Is there a way to prevent Webpack from evaluating certain env variables?
or am I going about it wrong and do I need to build the production bundle on Elastic Beanstalk first and then serve?

Worst case I can simply add the required values to a dotenv file and approach it that way. I would prefer to be able to make use of Elastic Beanstalks Enviroment Variables though.

Thanks in advance

***Update:***
To better explain below, I'm trying to access process.env variables during runtime in the server side script. The code is however built on my local machine before being deployed to AWS Elastic Beanstalk

*webpack.config.server*

```
'use strict';

const util = require('util');
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const CaseSensitivePathsPlugin = require('case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin');
// const WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin = require('react-dev-utils/WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin');
const paths = require('./paths');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
const getClientEnvironment = require('./env');

const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const base = require('./webpack.config.base');

const publicUrl = '';
// Get environment variables to inject into our app.
const env = getClientEnvironment(publicUrl);


const config = {
    target: 'node',
    entry: paths.serverIndexJs,
    externals: [nodeExternals()], // / in order to ignore all modules in node_modules folder
    output: {
        path: paths.serverBuild,
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            // "postcss" loader applies autoprefixer to our CSS.
            // "css" loader resolves paths in CSS and adds assets as dependencies.
            // "style" loader turns CSS into JS modules that inject <style> tags.
            // In production, we use a plugin to extract that CSS to a file, but
            // in development "style" loader enables hot editing of CSS.
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                include: [ path.resolve(paths.scss, 'vendor') ], // Global styles
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "isomorphic-style-loader" // creates style nodes from JS strings
                    }, {
                        loader: "css-loader", // translates CSS into CommonJS
                        options: {
                            importLoaders: 1,
                            sourceMap: true
                        }
                    }, {
                        loader: "postcss-loader",
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: true
                        }
                    }, {
                        loader: "sass-loader", // compiles Sass to CSS
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: true
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                exclude: [ path.resolve(paths.scss, 'vendor'), path.resolve(__dirname, '../node_modules') ], // Module styles
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "isomorphic-style-loader" // creates style nodes from JS strings
                    }, {
                        loader: "css-loader", // translates CSS into CommonJS
                        options: {
                            importLoaders: 1,
                            sourceMap: true,
                            modules: true,
                            localIdentName: '[path]___[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
                        }
                    }, {
                        loader: "postcss-loader",
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: true
                        }
                    }, {
                        loader: "sass-loader", // compiles Sass to CSS
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: true
                        }
                    }, {
                        loader: "sass-resources-loader",
                        options: {
                            resources: [
                                path.resolve(__dirname, '../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_functions.scss'),
                                path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/scss/config/**/*.scss'),
                                path.resolve(__dirname, '../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins/**/*.scss'),
                                path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/scss/helpers/**/*.scss'),
                            ]
                        }
                    }

                ]
            },
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        // Makes some environment variables available to the JS code, for example:
        // if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') { ... }. See `./env.js`.
        new webpack.DefinePlugin(env.stringified),
    ],
    node: {
        console: false,
        global: false,
        process: false,
        Buffer: false,
        __filename: false,
        __dirname: false,
        setImmediate: false,
    }
};

module.exports = merge(base, config);
```

Comment: whatr getClientEnvironment  does? what is its output?

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% clear on what you're trying to do, but it sounds like you want to pass only some of the environment vars to the `DefinePlugin`, not all of them...? If that's the case you can just write a little fn to filter or whitelist the env vars and pass the result to `DefinePlugin`. If an env var isn't included in your `DefinePlugin`, webpack will be unaware of it at build time.

Comment: Thanks Brandan, I think that is somewhat putting me on the right track. The issue is that in AWS Elastic Beanstalk, I'm defining key value pairs such as PORT. Elastic Beanstalk exposes these to the node application as env variables - process.env.PORT . As the application is being built on my local machine before deployment to AWS, these env variables are not available. I would like process.env.PORT to be available at runtime rather than being replaced with 'undefined' by Webpack during build. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

getClientEnvironment from env.js returned an object of key values which was then passed to DefinePlugin.

Although environment variables such as process.env.PORT weren't being passed to DefinePlugin they were being complied by Webpack as undefined.

This was due to getClientEnviroment returning the environment variables as an object of process.env

```
 { 'process.env': 
   { NODE_ENV: '"production"',
     PUBLIC_URL: '""',
     REACT_APP_HOST: '"localhost"',
     REACT_APP_PORT: '"8080"' 
    } 
  }
```

What I didn't realise was that in doing this, DefinePlugin overrides all process.env variables.

As per definePlugin's docs:

> When defining values for process prefer 'process.env.NODE_ENV':
>   JSON.stringify('production') over process: { env: { NODE_ENV:
>   JSON.stringify('production') } }. Using the latter will overwrite the
>   process object which can break compatibility with some modules that
>   expect other values on the process object to be defined.